# What is the correct way to serve a single static file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

The documentation only discusses mapping folders.

In expressjs I would create a route to single file with e.g.

```
app.get('/myfile', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('myfile.html', { root: 'site/', maxAge: 300000 });
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about redirecting to a different URL or embedding the static contents in the current output?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#serving-static-files)?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Of course, hence, as I say, it only discusses mapping folders not individual files

Comment: @DStanley the latter, embedding static contents in the current output - ideally with standard features of mapping static dirs e.g. caching, file watching, missing file errors etc.